Simulink system that increments every second (in sync with system time)
Currently, I have this system that increments every second:

The subsystem (which shouldn't be modified) is shown below:

Does anyone know how I should modify this such that the pulse generator is in sync with system time (i.e. get the system to increment whenever the "seconds" on the system clock increases)?
